# How attributes like ` v-b-modal` and `v-b-toggle` works? Where are they listened?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to add a custom attribute like these two and to trigger other events. But I can't find out how they work.

For example:

```
<b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal</b-button>

// Generated html5 tag
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Launch demo modal</button>
```

There's no extra attributes used on the generated html5 target for reference and also no event listener registered explicitly.

What's happening behind the scene? How v-b-modal got used?

Comment: [Solved](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source code at https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/directives/modal/modal.js to see how they are implemented.  They emit events on `$root`, which modal listens for.